# Python Groupby on custom brackets of values

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I got a question related to python groupby. I got this dataframe here :

```
    latlong               hour  formula_value_x
0   -37.853698 145.0562584  0   978.880733
1   -37.853698 145.0562584  1   535.458975
2   -37.853698 145.0562584  2   370.082577
3   -37.853698 145.0562584  3   348.519570
4   -37.853698 145.0562584  4   524.588282
5   -37.853698 145.0562584  5   1310.520435
6   -37.853698 145.0562584  6   3440.724656
7   -37.853698 145.0562584  7   5839.008447
8   -37.853698 145.0562584  8   6024.170196
9   -37.853698 145.0562584  9   5000.579879
10  -37.853698 145.0562584  10  4697.686943
```

I need to run a `groupby` on 1st 2 columns (`latlong` and `hours`) and find maximum. But I need to run the groupby on hours on brackets of hours like `0-5, 6-10, 11-16,17-20, 20-23`.

```
 df1.groupby(['latlong','hour'])['formula_value_x'].quantile(1)
```

is the basic way to do it without brackets. How can I do it with those brackets of hours?

So for example for a particular `latlong` value, the `groupby` will take all its formula_value for hours `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` and then take their max. 
After finding the maximum for such brackets of hours, I need to creaate a new column which will have the maximum value (found out previously) and these will be next to the hour belonging to same bracket.

So ..I need a result like this :

```
    latlong               hour  formula_value_x    max
0   -37.853698 145.0562584  0   978.880733        1310.520435
1   -37.853698 145.0562584  1   535.458975        1310.520435
2   -37.853698 145.0562584  2   370.082577        1310.520435
3   -37.853698 145.0562584  3   348.519570        1310.520435
4   -37.853698 145.0562584  4   524.588282        1310.520435
5   -37.853698 145.0562584  5   1310.520435       1310.520435
6   -37.853698 145.0562584  6   3440.724656       6024.170196
7   -37.853698 145.0562584  7   5839.008447       6024.170196 
8   -37.853698 145.0562584  8   6024.170196       6024.170196
9   -37.853698 145.0562584  9   5000.579879       6024.170196
10  -37.853698 145.0562584  10  4697.686943       6024.170196
```

Comment: Please post an extract of your dataframe as text, not as an image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to group the hours into a new column "hourgroup" and work with that.

```
df.loc[df.hour.isin([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 'hourgroup'] = 'HG1'
df.loc[df.hour.isin([6, 7, 8]), 'hourgroup'] = 'HG2'
....
```

Then collect the grouped values in a new dataframe. I'm seperating lat/long into two fields because of spaces in your example which split them on import.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['lat', 'long', 'hourgroup'])['formula_value_x'].max().reset_index()
```

Give the grouped maximum a better name. Max is a bad name because the function max exists.

```
df2.rename(columns={'formula_value_x': 'max_value_x'}, inplace=True)
```

Merge it with the original data frame

```
df_result = df.merge(df2, on=['lat', 'long', 'hourgroup'], how='left')

print(df_result)
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Although i was wondering if there is a way to do this without creating a new column for groups.

Comment: Sure, you can for example define a function to assign the hour group or fill a dictionary with your grouping rules and apply that. Note that you can also drop the hourgroup column when you are done with grouping.